# How to distinguish similar UserControls in ViewModel?

Tags: c#, mvvm, user-controls, windows-phone, datacontext

WP8 app. I have xaml page with 4 the same UserControls. For this moment it's look really simple:

```
<TextBlock Text="name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <CheckBox Content="chk1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
    <CheckBox Content="chk2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="119,0,0,0"/>
```

I want to store this data in collection of objects. Now I try to use DataContext and ICommand interface.
It's stupid to make 12 properties for every single controls so the question is how can I send to DataContext information about which one UserControl is operating now? it will be easier to use for example index of UserControls or something.

Im just learning about mvvm... Any advices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to approach this: data-context inheritance, or dependency properties.

The first way would be to make use of the fact that child controls inherit the parent's DataContext.  Let's say you have a main view-model with sub-view-models.  Then you can simply bind each UserControl to the appropriate view-model.  Eg

```
<local:MyUserControl DataContext="{Binding FirstSubViewModel}" />
<local:MyUserControl DataContext="{Binding SecondSubViewModel}" />
```

Your user control would then just assume that its DataContext has all the `ICommand` properties it needs.

---

The second approach would be to have your user control define [dependency properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221408(v=vs.95).aspx) of type `ICommand`:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty Command1Property = 
    DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Command1", typeof(ICommand),
    typeof(MyUserControl), null
    );
public ICommand Command1
{
    get { return (ICommand)GetValue(Command1Property); }
    set { SetValue(Command1Property, value); }
}
```

This way, consumers of your control will be able to bind the commands using any binding method.  Eg:

```
<local:MyUserControl Command1="{Binding chk1Command}" />
<local:MyUserControl Command1="{Binding ElementName=someControl,Path=SomeCommand}" />
```

The only trick here is that you have to somehow bind to to the dependency properties from within your user control -- this is tricky in Silverlight, because there is no `RelativeSource=FindAncestor` binding.  One way to do it is to set the LayoutRoot's DataContext to be the control itself.  So if your makrup is like this:

```
<UserControl ...>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <TextBlock Text="name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <CheckBox Content="chk1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
        <CheckBox Content="chk2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="119,0,0,0"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Then in the constructor, you'd have:

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LayoutRoot.DataContext = this;
    }
}
```